# Identical points which overlapp in plot_ly 3D scatter plot in R

Tags: r-plotly

So I have for example a dataset below:

```
name<-c("A", "K","A","B","B","J","L","B","C","D","E","F","G")
Dim1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4)
Dim2 <- c(5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2)
Dim3 <- c(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3)


data<-data.frame(name,Dim1,Dim2,Dim3)
```

I am plotting this data using plot_ly as below:

```
plot_ly(data,x=~Dim1,y=~Dim2,z=~Dim3,type = "scatter3d",mode="markers", 
hovertemplate = ~paste('Point:<extra></extra>',data$name,
                       '</br></br>Dim1:', data$Dim1,
                       '</br>Dim2:', data$Dim2,
                       '</br>Dim3:', data$Dim3))
```

[image]

The problem I'm having here is that identical points are only shown as a single point, with only one name given instead of all the names of the point that have the same coordinate.

Is there a way to maybe increase the size of the marker according to the number of points that have the identical coordinates? The more points that have the identical coordinate, the bigger it's shape(marker) should be. Also, I want to be able to show the hover info of the names of all the identical points, such that in the picture above, it should show Point:A,K.

I've seen somthing similar to http://www.rensenieuwenhuis.nl/r-sessions-13-overlapping-data-points/ in Sizeplot {plotrix}, but its only in 2D and nothing in plot-ly for 3D.

Comment: Hello Gaby! I stumbled on the same problem, but I'm using Python-plotly, therefore I can not answer with a particular solution in R. In Python I manneged to surpass this issue by creating a new DataFrame (matrix) with only one of each points and two new collumns. For instance:  | x =1 | y = 5 | z = 2| points = "A, K" | rep = 2 |. Finally you set an size parameter as rep.